# How can l extract a section of the pandas dataframe like marked in the picture below?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Click here to open the marked image]

I am trying to extract the section (matrix) of the numbers in pandas dataframe like as marked in the given picture embedded above.
Please anyone who can assist me, I want to perform analytics based on the section (matrix) of a bigger data frame. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are you refering given initial and final columns, rows?

Comment: I want to move through the entire dataframe and extract the matrix from it and perform analysis of the extracted matrix or section of the bigger dataframe

Comment: How do you define the matrix to extract?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: df.iloc[5:20, 6:14] assming your dataframe is called df

Comment: Thanks @dafmedinama, it solve the first part of my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.iloc[]` function to select the rows and columns you want.

```
dataframe.iloc[5:15,6:15]
```

This should select rows 5-14 and columns 6-14.
Not sure if the numbers are correct but I think this method is what you were looking for.

edit: changed .loc[] to .iloc[] because we're using index values, and cleaned it up a bit

Here is the code to iterate over the whole dataframe

```
#df = big data frame
shape = (10,10) #shape of matrix to be analyzed, here is 10x10
step = 1 #step size, iterate over every number
        #or
step = 10 #step size, iterate block by block
        #keep in mind, iterating by block will leave some data out at the end of the rows and columns
#you can set step = shape if you are working  with a matrix that isn't square, just be sure to change step in the code below to step[0] and step[1] respectively 
for row in range( 0, len(df[0]) - shape[0]+1, step): #number of rows of big dataframe - number of rows of matrix to be analyzed 
   for col in range(0, len(df.iloc[0,:]) - shape[1]+1, step): #number of columns of big dataframe - number of columns of matrix to be analized 
        matrix = df.iloc[row:shape[0]+row, col:shape[1]+col] #slice out matrix and set it equal to 'matrix'
        #analize matrix here
```

This is basically the same as @dafmedinama said, i just added more commenting and simplified specifying the shape of the matrix as well as included a step variable if you don't want to iterate over every single number every time you move the matrix.

Comment: If you already use loc, why not `dataframe.loc[6:15, 5:15]`?

Comment: Thanks @Roim, that's much cleaner

Comment: thanks @GeorgeSebastiaanvanHeerden. l solve the first step of my problem. However can l do this iteratively coz l want to moving through the entire dataframe collecting matrix of the same size and be able to continue with analytics per each matrx

Comment: @gsoft so the idea is to define a submatrix dimension and iterate for all possible submatrices inside the dataframe?

Comment: @dafmedinama,   exactly its what l want to do? The data frame has a shape of (381, 510).

Comment: @GeorgeSebastiaanvanHeerden

"#keep in mind, iterating by block will leave some data out at the end of the rows and columns"



How can we cover these leftover blocks as well?

Answer (score 0):

Be sub_rows and sub_cols the dimension of the datafram to be extracted:

```
import pandas as pd

sub_rows = 10 # Amount of rows to be extracted
sub_cols = 3  # Amount of columns to be extracted


if sub_rows > len(df.index):
    print("Defined sub dataframe rows are more than in the original dataframe")
elif sub_cols > len(df.columns):
    print("Defined sub dataframe columns are more than in the original dataframe")
else:
    for i in range(0,len(df.index)-sub_rows):
        for j in range(0, len(df.columns)):
            d.iloc[i:i+sub_rows, j:j+sub_cols] # Extracted dataframe
            # Put here the code you need for your analysis
```